# Copy and Paste inside DataGridViewTextBox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I am attempting to do a really simple copy and paste inside of a DataGridView cell using Ctrl+C and CTRL+ V.
I don't need to be able to copy or paste multiple cells, just the selected text of a single selected cell.

Edit mode for the DataGridView is set to EditOnEnter because they didn't like having to double click to edit the value.

Neither CTRL+C nor CTRL+V work normally inside the cell.

I found a workaround, but it's really buggy:

```
Private Sub dgParts_EditingControlShowing(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles dgParts.EditingControlShowing
    AddHandler e.Control.KeyUp, AddressOf dgParts_TextBox_KeyUp
End Sub

Private Sub dgParts_TextBox_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.C AndAlso e.Modifiers = Keys.Control Then
        Clipboard.SetText(sender.SelectedText)
    End If
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.V AndAlso e.Modifiers = Keys.Control Then
        sender.SelectedText = Clipboard.GetText
    End If
End Sub
```

For some reason KeyUp triggers multiple times, so when I do a paste it inserts the text 5 times.

I tried switching it over to a KeyDown instead of KeyUp, but then it triggers when I hit CTRL, and not when I also hit C or V.

It really doesn't seem like it should be this hard to do something so simple, so I'm hoping that I'm just missing something that will make it just work.

Comment: *Neither CTRL+C nor CTRL+V work normally inside the cell.* What does CTRL+V and CTRL+C do in the cell without that code?

Comment: @preciousbetine Nothing at all. Does not copy, does not paste, does not type out a C or a V.

Comment: @AndyD273 Are you finding that each time you move to a text box, the number of 'pastes' increases? Is the cell you want to edit the fifth one along?

Comment: @JayV yeah, it pastes once, in the first column, twice in the second, three times in the third, and so on.

Comment: It's important to remove the handlers you are creating as @JayV has already mentioned. On another note, `Object` doesn't have a member called `SelectedText`, turn `Option Strict On`...

Comment: `CTRL-C` and `CTRL-V` work as usual in an Edit control. You don't need to handle anything, unless you need to support only specific DataFormats, filtering the data pasted in.

Comment: @Jimi not sure why, but for some reason it doesn't. You can right click and copy/paste using the context menu, but not the keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Then you have code somewhere that's handling key presses an it's tampering with the default behaviour.

Comment: Try replacing the control with a **new** one!

Comment: @Jimi This is correct. The program had an Edit menu with all the usual cut, copy, paste options with some strange behavior on the back end. Not really sure why it was done that way long ago, but removing the entire edit menu did solve the problem. I may see about putting it back the right way, if anyone notices that it is gone...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you add an Event Handler in code using syntax like

```
AddHandler e.Control.KeyUp, AddressOf dgParts_TextBox_KeyUp
```

It is good practice to precede that line of code with its opposite, to remove any previously added Event Handlers. If you don't then you are likely to encounter the situation you are facing with the same event being handled multiple times.

Change the Sub `dgParts_EditingControlShowing` to contain `RemoveHandler e.Control.KeyUp, AddressOf dgParts_TextBox_KeyUp`

Final version should be like:

```
Private Sub NewMethod(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs)
    RemoveHandler e.Control.KeyUp, AddressOf dgParts_TextBox_KeyUp
    AddHandler e.Control.KeyUp, AddressOf dgParts_TextBox_KeyUp
End Sub
```

Comment: This did work,and I did learn something new, though thanks to the main comments I was able to find the root cause of the problem.

Comment: @AndyD273 It's a pleasure to help in any way